# Spock bug with testing private method?

Tags: java, groovy, spock

Can somebody tell me if this is a bug or intended behavior.

I know in Spock I can test private methods:

```
def "test with private"() {
    given:
        FileContentValidator fileContentValidator = new FileContentValidator(1)

    when:
        fileContentValidator.validateCustomerSiteId("") // this is a private method

    then:
        true // succeeds
}
```

But when I try the same thing using a Spock Spy, it fails:

```
def "test with private on spy"() {
    given:
        FileContentValidator fileContentValidator = Spy(FileContentValidator, constructorArgs: [1])

    when:
        fileContentValidator.validateCustomerSiteId("") // this is a private method

    then:
        true // does not get here
}
```

I get an exception:

`groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.shoppertrak.device.management.web.validator.ophour.FileContentValidator$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$7ff6a42.validateCustomerSiteId() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: []`

Comment: Seems rash to call it a bug. A spy's job is to spy on the methods in the contract, which is a flexible concept, but hard to find a definition that includes things that are declared to be private.

Comment: Then perhaps that puts it in the "intended behavior" category

Comment: Is FileContentValidator a class type or is it an interface type? A spy is always based on a real object you must provide a class type rather than an interface type.

Comment: `FileContentValidator` is a class

Comment: Try changing the method to protected.

Comment: `protected` did work as temporary workaround. But I was able to find a way to write my test without requiring a Spy, so was able to put it back to `private`

Answer (score 1):

I think this is due to how the `cglib` works.  When testing an existing concrete class, Spock doesn't get involved in the byte code, so you're taking advantage of a flaw in Groovy that give you access to private methods.   When you `spy` or `mock` the same class, the  Spock/cglib manipulation steps in and changes the resulting byte code. The end product is a method that is truly private, thus you can't access it.

There are probably hacks you can use to get around it, but you're probably better off adding something like a `CustomerSiteIdValidator` class with a public `validateCustomerSiteId()` that gets injected into your `FileContentValidator` class.  Then you can easily mock it and isolate responsibilities.

Someone suggested adding the ability to `Spy` private methods, but the ticket was closed as Won't Fix
https://github.com/spockframework/spock/issues/403